# What does the phrase "branded on my feet" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, songs

It is a line from Bob Dylan's Mr. Tambourine Man:

> Though I know that evenin's empire has returned into sand, Vanished
>   from my hand, Left me blindly here to stand but still not sleeping. My
>   weariness amazes me, I'm branded on my feet, I have no one to meet And
>   the ancient empty street's too dead for dreaming.

I find the literal meaning does not fit here. What do you think?

Comment: They might not "mean" anything at all. Song lyrics may be chosen to fit a certain beat or rhyme pattern,to reference certain imagery or simply to evoke certain emotions, using words that would be unusual, ungrammatical, or indeed nonsensical in prose.

Answer (score 2):

> I find the literal meaning does not fit here.

That is often the case with song lyrics. Figure of speech is heavily used, as is the case here.

[OED link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brand). Definitions of the verb:

> 1. Mark with a branding iron.
>    1.1 Mark indelibly.
>    1.2 Mark out as having a particular bad or shameful quality.
> 2. Assign a brand name to.
>    2.1 The promotion of a particular product or company by means of advertising and distinctive design.

Definition 1 (mark with a branding iron) is correct here, but it is used figuratively. Figuring out the meaning of the lyrics is subjective (and somewhat off topic), but I see two distinct possibilties here:

1. He's trying to say that his feet have burn marks/scars on them. Likely because he has been using his feet intensively, and they now hurt.
2. He's trying to say that his feet bear the scars of a past event. The rest of the lyrics seem to refer to something that has now disappeared. His branded feet may be a remnant of that which is now lost, in the sense that "being branded" means "having a mark left on you". Somewhat of an analogy (and maybe even exactly what the singer means): *There was a party. The party is now over. There is no proof left that there was ever a party, except for the sore feet that the singer has from dancing at the party. His feet bear the scars of having danced at the party.*

There is a lot of overlap between these two options. However, option 1 focuses on **the existence of the wounds**, and option 2 focuses on the fact that **the wounds are proof of something in the past**.

Because of the figurative usage, it's hard to figure out what exactly is meant with the sentence. But "brand" in and of itself seems clear: **visibly marked or scarred**.